# Invoke Manage controller GET method from account controller login page in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Want to invoke `AddPhoneNumber` method in Manage controller from Account Controller Login Page. I have a checkbox in Login page which I have implemented for OTP.

What I want is that when checkbox is checked, it should invoke `AddPhoneNumber` GET method from Manage Controller to open the page.

Manage controller

```
 // GET: /Manage/AddPhoneNumber
        public ActionResult AddPhoneNumber()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

AddPhoneNumber page

```
@model Aayumitra.Models.AddPhoneNumberViewModel

        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPhoneNumber", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <h4>Add a phone number</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send verification code" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

Login Page

```
@using Aayumitra.Models
@model LoginViewModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Mobile Number / Email ID</label>

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Mobile Number / Email ID" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm password-input", placeholder = "Password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="remember-password" id="remember-pass-check" onclick="triggerLink()">
                    <label for="">Login with OTP instead of password</label>
                </div>
    }

function triggerLink() {
        debugger;
        var theUrl ='@Url.Action("AddPhoneNumber","Manage", Model)';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

In your `triggerLink()` method, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function triggerLink() {
      debugger;
      var theUrl ='@Url.Action("AddPhoneNumber","Manage")';
      window.location.href = theUrl;
  }
</script>
```

Also, don' tthink you need to pass the model along, since your controller action does not look like it's expecting it...

Comment: It is not working. When It invokes, it uses this URL `http://localhost:49812/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FManage%2FAddPhoneNumber`. And the page does not appear.

Comment: Hmmm. not sure what you've got different. I just recreated your code, and it worked with the following changes: wrapped your javascript in <script> tags; I don't have your model, so I'm not passing through a model. Updated my response to reflect these changes. When I view source, the `theUrl` var is '/Manage/AddPhoneNumber' (as expected), and the redirect fires as expected

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I have used `Individual User Accounts` to create my application where I can use default created login and register page. If we put checkbox in login page and write JQeury logic inside login page then it does not invoke to `AddPhoneNumber` which is under `Manage` controller. But strangely, If I create `No Authentication` application and do the same then it works. Please guide me why the behavior is different.

Comment: When you view source on the login page, what is the value in javascript for `theUrl`?

Comment: It gives me `/Manage/AddPhoneNumber` .But It appears like `http://localhost:49812/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FManage%2FAddPhoneNumber` in the url.

Comment: You should use Fiddler or similar to track it down. What's likely happening is the javascript is redirecting correctly to '/Manage/AddPhoneNumber', but then *that* page requires authentication to load, and so is redirecting to 'Login', with the ReturnUrl. You need to disable authentication required for the '/Manage/AddPhoneNumber' endpoint

Comment: I will try to find a way to disable authentication required for this page